# Spring, CXF, java.lang.Class cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Class;

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I get the following Error and can't understand the problem of it:

> Error creating bean with name 'someJobBean' defined in class path
>   resource [xx/yy//zz.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested
>   exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   Factory method [public java.lang.Object
>   org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create()] threw exception;
>   nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Class
>   cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Class;

Any helpful information is welcomed!

Comment: ...Could you provide some _code_?  All we know right now is that it's getting a `Class` where it expects a `Class[]`.

Comment: You we're right! I fixed it.. the thing was that the bean declared in my `zz.xml` was not up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All we know right now is that it's getting a Class where it expects a Class[].  We'd know more with some code.